# How do SQL Server variables work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table with salary of multiple employees. 
I need to calculate score for these employees using a derived number (mean and stddev) and include it as a new column.

I know I can do this in the select statement, but if I wanted see if I can use variables.

So that changes can be made dynamically. I am new to SQL and just trying to learn things here.

```
declare @Weight int,
        @weight2 int,
        @Mean int,
        @StdDevn int,
        @Variance int

set @Weight = 30
set @weight2 = (POWER(@weight,2)/100)

SELECT @Mean = AVG(salary) FROM [live].[dbo].[salary]
SELECT @StdDevn = STDEV(salary) FROM [live].[dbo].[salary]

SELECT @Variance = (POWER(@StdDevn,2)/100)
-- I should include some code here so that the above variable are passed to below query
SELECT * FROM [live].[dbo].[salary], (([salary]-@Mean)/@StdDevn)
```

**Error:**

> Must declare variable @Mean, Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is how you  are trying to select.

The variable `@Mean` is declared and it would work if the final select would be something like below:

```
SELECT *, 
       (([salary]-@Mean)/@StdDevn) as SomeOtherCol
FROM [live].[dbo].[salary]
```

The `SomeOtherCol` will be then shown as the last column of your result set.